# Visualization Using Tableau

Tags: hive, tableau-api

I am new to [Tableau](https://www.tableau.com/), and having performance issues and need some help. I have a hive query result in **Azure Blob Storage** named as **part-00000**.
The issue having this performance is I want to execute the custom query in Tableau and generates the graphical reports at Tableau. 
So can I do this? How ? 
I have 7.0 M Data in Hive table.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Screen shoot of data source connection]

you can find custom query in data source connection check linked image

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider creating an extract instead of a live connection. Additional considerations would include hiding unused fields and using filters at the data source level to limit data as per requirement.